# LINQ select depending on inner collection value

Tags: c#, linq, select, collections

I have this piece of code:

```
public string Label { get; set; }

public bool IsSpoon(out Spoon sp) 
{
    sp = null;
    foreach (Tool t in Tools.GetAllItems())
        if ((sp = t.AllSpoons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Label == this.Label)) != null)
            break;

    return sp != null;
}
```

How can this be optimised via LINQ?

I thought of something like this but this isn't allowed:

```
public string Label { get; set; }

public bool IsSpoon(out Spoon sp) 
{
    return Tools.GetAllItems().FirstOrDefault(x => (sp = x.AllSpoons.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Label == this.Label)) != null) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :** I did not notice the `sp` parameter, here is an update:

```
sp = Tools
    .GetAllItems()
    .SelectMany(x => x.AllSpoons)
    .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Label == this.Label);
return sp != null;
```

Comment: same as Martin his code: how will this fill up my 'sp' parameter?

Comment: @juFo Oops, I did not notice that `sp` is actually an output parameter. Please see the update.

Comment: @Rawling Yes, thanks for the correction. This was a copy/paste from the OP's attempt, and I deleted the wrong part :)

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the list with [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).  Then you don't have to do anything tricky like assigning a value in the middle of a LINQ statement.

```
public bool IsSpoon(out Spoon sp) 
{
    sp = Tools.GetAllItems().SelectMany(t => t.AllSpoons)
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Label == this.Label);
    return sp != null;
}
```

Here is the essentially equivalent query syntax:

```
sp = (from tool in Tools.GetAllItems()
      from spoon in tool.AllSpoons
      where spoon.Label == this.Label
      select spoon).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsSpoon(out Spoon sp) 
{ 
    return Tools.GetAllItems()
        .SelectMany(t => t.AllSpoons)
        .Any(x => x.Label == this.Label);
}
```

Comment: how will this fill up my 'sp' parameter?